# twitter bootstrap: glyphicons in (right floated) drop down navbar menu not displaying correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to include an icon in a drop down menu. The icon is causing the menu to be rendered incorrectly (it appears the icon is being repeated on the menu bar and the menu).
snippet:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="brand" href="#">Project X</a>

    <div class="nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Menu 1
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Menu 2
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><i class="icon-off"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to close your tag.

```
<i class="icon-off"></i>
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. A second pair of eyes are always useful at times like these :) tx!

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that and all though the menu displayed looks better than before, it still looks kinda weird in the sense that the icons are forcing line break in the menu, i.e. an icon is shown on one line and the menu text is shown in a line underneath the icon ... weird, I've never seen that before. I first tried `<li><i class="icon-off"></i><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>` like you suggested, and then `<li><i class="icon-off"><a href="#">Sign Out</a></i></li>` both resulted in strange looking menus. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain Sara (I'm not really a web developer) - could you elaborate with an example element?. e.g. I mean how should I modify a menu item like this for example: `<li><i class="icon-off"></i><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>` ?

Comment: HTML: `<li class="nowrap"><i class="icon-off"></i><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>` / CSS: `.nowrap { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19546/discussion-between-homunculus-reticulli-and-sara)

Comment: I would suggest posting a separate question about your new nav problem, as this one is regarding repeating icons. You will likely receive more effective assistance in a question that specifically addresses your new issue.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting this resolved - been xtra busy. Yup, I guess you're right. I'll accept your answer and respost the nav prob in another question later on.

Comment: add `.nav>li>a {display:inline-block;}` in your css and `padding-left:0px` to your anchor element

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
<li> <a href="#"> <i class="icon-off"> </i>  Sign Out </a> </li>
```